# Where are joomla repeatable field values stored in database?

Tags: module

In which table are stored the data of a simple repeatable field of a module. I mean when you hit save  somewhow the field values are saved somewhere right?
So the question is where they are saved? In which table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are stored as a json_encoded array in the `params` of the `#_modules` table of the respective module.

Comment: thank you!!! I was searching all day!!